# Combining two views of same numpy array into single view without copying the array?

Tags: python, numpy, view, slice

I have a large 2d numpy array and I want to remove subsets of it and handle what remains to a function. I need to do this for many subsets, and thus I would ideally not want to create a copy of the array each time. The function doesn't change any values in the array.

```
mat = np.load(filename)
mat_1 = mat[:i,:]
mat_2 = mat[j:,:]
```

So far, mat_1 and mat_2 are views.
Then I would like to do

```
mat_s = np.concatenate((mat_1,mat_2))
result = func(mat_s)
```

but without making a copy. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just use `mat[j:i,:]`?

Comment: @Kasramvd this would be different from what he is doing. Just think of an array of shape `(100, 1)` with `i=50` and `j=20`. The resulting `np.concatenate` creates an overlapping resulting array, whereas your `mat[j:i,:]` does not.

Comment: should have specified, but j is larger than i. That would just return an empy array.

Comment: Aha, so if `j > i`, then `np.concatenate` does not create an overlapping array, but concats two separated arrays. Still Kasramvd's solution won't work. filippo has shown a good way to deal with that.

Comment: @filippo Yes, that's right it will actually repeat some rows.

Comment: @Kasramvd sorry deleted my comment by mistake and don't know how to get it back, anyway he said `j` is larger than `i` so my comment was kind of pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since memory-views can only be created using a fixed set of `strides`, you will have to create a copy in your case, where `mat.shape[0] > j > i`.

That means views will only work, if you want to have a view to every x-th element in the array:

```
mat = np.arange(20)
view = mat[slice(0, 20, 4)]
view
# Out[41]: array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16])
```

So this only works for views to equally spaced cells. But if you want to have a view to one contiguous `slice(0, i)` and another contiguous  `slice(j, mat.shape[0])`, it won't work. You'll have to make a copy.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't think to mention it, but the order of the elements in the array is not important, so this works nicely.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the rows that you want to remove and pass it directly into the function

```
mat = np.load(filename)
mat_s = np.delete(mat,list(range(i,j)),axis=0)
```

you can delete 2 diff subsets by adding the list of ranges like

```
mat_s = np.delete(mat,list(range(i,j))+list(range(k,l)),axis=0)
```

the above removes the rows i:j and k:l

Comment: This method also returns a copy of the array.