# Combine two numpy views into a single view by stacking along one axis

Tags: python, numpy, view

Am i conceptually not grasping something (only similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330112/combining-two-views-of-same-numpy-array-into-single-view-without-copying-the-arr)) or why does stacking multiple views along the first `axis=0` not result in a new view? The problem: Multiple 2d arrays of which single rows should be combined into a single new matrix also being a view not to increase memory-use. example:

```
recs = np.arange(2*2).reshape(2,2)
recs2 = np.arange(4,2*2*2).reshape(2,2)
print(recs)
print(recs2)
rv0 = recs[0].view()
r2v0 = recs2[0].view()
#now combine
mview = np.stack([rv0,r2v0], axis=0)
print(mview)
np.may_share_memory(mview,recs2)
```

prints

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
[[4 5]
 [6 7]]
[[0 1]
 [4 5]]
False #sure a copy
```

Is it because the 2d arrays are separate memory regions and the resulting array would not allow slicing etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `concatenate` (`stack` is just another way of calling that) create an array with its own databuffer.  It's never a `view` of the original(s).

Your `rv0` is an array (`np.ndarray`) like `recs`, with its own shape, dtype and strides.  It just shares the databuffer with `recs`.  It can be described as 'a view' of `recs`, but otherwise it is used like any other array.  It's not specially marked as a `view` class or object.

```
In [409]: recs = np.arange(2*2).reshape(2,2)
     ...: recs2 = np.arange(4,2*2*2).reshape(2,2)
```

Since `recs` is a `reshape` of an array produced by `arange` it too is 'a view'.  That could be made more obvious with:

```
temp = np.arange(2*2)
recs = temp.reshape(2,2)
np.may_share_memory(temp, recs)
```

We can get a snap shot, so to speak, of the databuffer with `ravel()` (which just produces a 1d view):

```
In [411]: recs.ravel()
Out[411]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
In [412]: recs2.ravel()
Out[412]: array([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Now look at the `stack`:

```
In [414]: mview = np.stack([recs,recs2], axis=0)
In [415]: mview
Out[415]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
In [416]: mview.ravel()
Out[416]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

The `ravel` of `mview` is not a subset of `Out[411]` and `Out[412]`.  `mview` has to have its own contiguous databuffer.  There's no mechanism for making an array that shares memory with 2 or more other arrays (unless they too share memory).

---

Even a `stack` made from slices of the same array has its own databuffer:

```
In [420]: x = np.stack((recs[0],recs[1]))
In [421]: x
Out[421]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
In [422]: np.may_share_memory(recs, x)
Out[422]: False
```

I like to use `__array_interface__` to check the databuffer location (other defining attributes):

```
In [423]: recs.__array_interface__
Out[423]: 
{'data': (37584304, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}

In [424]: x.__array_interface__
Out[424]: 
{'data': (37614336, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```